# Angular fade in template

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a template popup being loaded in via a controller function. Is there a way I can fade in the template. I have tried adding a separate class, hooking it to the `ng-show` class.

HTML:

```
<div class="contact-form">
    <div ng-include="contactTemplate" class="fade"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.contactForm = function() {
    $scope.contactTemplate = 'sections/popups/contact.html';
};
```

Comment: u tried with ng-class , ? .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) and add simple css animations (there are a lot of good tutorials out there).

The available animations can be found in the [ngInclude docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) at "Animations".

*PS: To nicely format code blocks insert a linebreak and indent code by four spaces*